# Error in calling xml parser method

Tags: iphone, ios5

I am using retailligence barcode api and using nsxml parser method to parse the response below is the code but it didn't give call to parsing method. What's wrong there. Please help

```
{   NSString *myxmlstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://apitest.retailigence.com/v1.2/products?apikey=rMMzX5IDYVmTjQ3A7D9sZXukjKiZVmdD&barcode=%@&latitude=37.439097&longitude=-122.175806",brcode];
NSLog(@"my myxmlsstr is %@",myxmlstr);
dataselected = NO;
NSURL * xmlURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myxmlstr];



myParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];



myParser.delegate = self;

BOOL success = [myParser parse];
if(success){
    NSLog(@"Properly done ");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"not done");
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an error in code and I have to just replace this code

```
NSURL * xmlURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myxmlstr];
```

with this code

```
NSURL * xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:myxmlstr];
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

more information about parsing you get if you call `-parserError` or use method from protocol `- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError` to obtain error informations